# How can I know where digits are on a double

Tags: ios

I would like to display a number according to the position of the first uncertain digit.

Hence for a number as 203.32134 with the first uncertain digit being 0.01 I would like to display 203.321 (all the certain digits plus the first uncertain as is and the second rounded.)

But I do not know how I could write a string format with a %x.yf in order to get my string as I would like.

Could anyone help?

Comment: How do you defined (and determine) the "first uncertain digit"?

Comment: The usual trick is to multiply the number by int(1.0/precision), then round that to the nearest integer, then multiply that by precision

Comment: Did you mean first uncertain digit would be 0.001?

Comment: No I mean first uncertain digit would be 0.01. When displaying a quantity, I display the quantity numerical value up to the first uncertain digit and the uncertainty value up to the second uncertain digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSNumberFormatter` and set minimum/maximum number of significant fractions.